# How can I get a Tasks assigned Thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task, threadpool

How can I get a Task's assigned Thread, when it is running in c#?
I would like to get the thread of the task for debugging. 
I tried modify Task class, but Microsoft solved it without it.

Comment: What are you trying to do? A task can use any thread from the threadpool to execute. The Thread ID will be useless outside it ie, once the task terminates and the thread goes back to the pool. You shouldn't care what the thread is nor try to find the same thread for another task, use thread-local storage etc

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos A thread doesn't necessarily belong to the thread-pool, it can be a thread created by the `Thread` class :).

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov or the UI thread, depending on the TaskScheduler you use. I think this is beside the point though. It shouldn't matter which Thread was used by a Task. If it does, something fishy is going on, like using thread-local storage or modifying unsafe objects from different tasks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I see what you mean. OP should clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Same way you get the managed thread id for any given method. Simply:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Along with the other answer, if you are using VS, add a name to the task and thread.  This really helps and shows up in the VS debugger.  Debug -> Windows -> Threads, then all running threads will show up there.  Same as locals, you can add a watch on a thread, along with many other things.